# Pearson correlation on big numpy matrices

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, pearson

I have a 24000 * 316 numpy matrix, each row represents a time series with 316 time points, and I am computing pearson correlation between each pair of these time series. Meaning as a result I would have a 24000 * 24000 numpy matrix having pearson values. 
My problem is that this takes a very long time. I have tested my pipeline on smaller matrices (200 * 200) and it works (though still slow). I am wondering if it is expected to be this slow (takes more than a day!!!). And what I might be able to do about it...
If it helps this is my code... nothing special or hard..

```
def SimMat(mat,name):

    mrange = mat.shape[0]
    print "mrange:", mrange
    nTRs = mat.shape[1]
    print "nTRs:", nTRs

    SimM = numpy.zeros((mrange,mrange))



    for i in range(mrange):

        SimM[i][i] = 1

    for i in range (mrange):
        for j in range(i+1, mrange):
            pearV = scipy.stats.pearsonr(mat[i], mat[j])

            if(pearV[1] <= 0.05):
                if(pearV[0] >= 0.5):
                    print "Pearson value:", pearV[0]
                    SimM[i][j] = pearV[0]
                    SimM[j][i] = 0
            else:

                SimM[i][j] = SimM[j][i] = 0

    numpy.savetxt(name, SimM)




    return SimM, nTRs
```

Thanks

Comment: You should have a look at the indentation in your code sample (and edit your post to fix it!). It isn't right, and it does affect whether your program will run as presented.

Comment: What are you going to do with that 24000*24000 matrix?  Perhaps you can work in batches and aggregate the partial results, so you never need the full 24000*24000 matrix in memory or on disk.

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for pointing that out. Indentation wasn't proper after pasting the code here. But the original code has proper indentation, meaning it is working and I have a performance issue.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser After obtaining the huge matrix I am going to threshold it based on a certain method (FDR), in which process I would need all the pearson values at the same time, so I have to keep them... Maybe I can figure something out ... I have to think about it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with your implementation is the amount of memory you'll need to store the correlation coefficients (at *least* 4.5GB). There is no reason to keep the already computed coefficients in memory. For problems like this, I like to use hdf5 to store the intermediate results since they work nicely with numpy. Here is a complete, minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

# Create the dataset
h5 = h5py.File("data.h5",'w')
h5["test"] = np.random.random(size=(24000,316))
h5.close()

# Compute dot products
h5 = h5py.File("data.h5",'r+')
A  = h5["test"][:]

N   = A.shape[0]
out = h5.require_dataset("pearson", shape=(N,N), dtype=float)

for i in range(N):
    out[i] = [pearsonr(A[i],A[j])[0] for j in range(N)]
```

Testing the first 100 rows suggests this will only take 8 hours on a single core. If you parallelized it, it should have linear speedup with the number of cores.

Comment: Thank you! I believe this will make everything so much faster and is what I needed to know!